# Run a bash script at reboot or shutdown opposed to Start up or instantaneously

Tags: bash, shutdown, reboot

It is a simple script that changes the hostname to computer serial numbers for easier tracking. However we need this to run at shutdown or reboot. What is best way to Call this to do so.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Get the Serial Number of the Machine
sn=$(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial/ {print $4}')

# Set the ComputerName, HostName and LocalHostName
scutil --set ComputerName $sn

scutil --set HostName $sn

scutil --set LocalHostName $sn

fi
```

Comment: You can write your `bash` script -- And inside your `crontab` you can put the line: `@reboot  bash /path/to/bash/file`  -- It will run the script as soon as `cron` is online during reboot ..

Answer (score 0):

Use your `crontab` to do this ..  If this is a system process within your bash script, I would use the `sudo` command when editing `crontab` to ensure the correct user executes the cron job.  In this case `root` would execute your bash script.  The easiest method is to create a bash file wherever you want it to reside that makes sense -- IE

```
/etc/my_reboot_crons/checkSerial.sh
```

Then use the following command to edit your `crontab` --

```
sudo crontab -e
```

If you have never used it before, you will be asked which editor you wish to use (I choose VIM) most choose Nano for it's ease of use.

Insert the following line:

```
@reboot bash /etc/my_reboot_crons/checkSerial.sh
```

OR if you don't want `/var/mail/root` to fill up with outputs from the command you can use

```
 @reboot bash /etc/my_reboot_crons/checkSerial.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

If you wanted to run the command more often than reboot, say every day at midnight, or once an hour ..  `crontab` was specifically designed for that -- hence the **cron** in `crontab`.

Here is a [REFERENCE](https://crontab.guru/examples.html) to help familiarize yourself with `crontab`